# How to check EXOPSSession is still active?

Tags: powershell

if there is a way to check that EXOPSSession is active on PowerShell ISE?

I was searching through the net and could not find any examples

I am using connect-EXOPSSession

EDIT ok i solved by myself so i post it to help others
I added below funciton and IF later

```
function PSSessionConnected {
    Get-PSSession
    $result =  Get-PSSession | Select State
    return $result
}
 #Later somewhere 
        if (-not (PSSessionConnected -eq "Opened")) {
        Write-Host "Connecting"
        Import-Module $((Get-ChildItem -Path $($env:LOCALAPPDATA+"\Apps\2.0\") -Filter CreateExoPSSession.ps1 -Recurse ).FullName | Select-Object -Last 1)
        Connect-EXOPSSession -UserPrincipalName $MFAUsername
        }
        Else {Continue}
```

Comment: Please Put you solution as an answer and the question as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DIT ok i solved by myself so i post it to help others I added below funciton and IF later

```
function PSSessionConnected {
    Get-PSSession
    $result =  Get-PSSession | Select State
    return $result
}
 #Later somewhere 
        if (-not (PSSessionConnected -eq "Opened")) {
        Write-Host "Connecting"
        Import-Module $((Get-ChildItem -Path $($env:LOCALAPPDATA+"\Apps\2.0\") -Filter CreateExoPSSession.ps1 -Recurse ).FullName | Select-Object -Last 1)
        Connect-EXOPSSession -UserPrincipalName $MFAUsername
        }
        Else {Continue}
```